# Indirect addressing with + and []

Tags: assembly, addressing-mode

Im a bit new to the asm stuff. Looking through asm generated from C for TI's C28x CPU and have the instruction

```
MOVL *+XAR4[0],ACC
```

I know its a long operand move instruction that takes the value in the accumulator and puts it in the location pointed at by.... what?

XAR4 is auxiliary register 4 but what does the '+' and '[0]' do? Will they take extra cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section 5.6 "*Indirect Addressing Modes"* of the *"TMS320C28x DSP CPU and Instruction Set
Reference Guide"*:

```
*+XARn[3bit]
32bitDataAddr(31:0) = XARn + 3bit
Note: The immediate value is treated as an unsigned 3-bit value.
```

So it will store `ACC` at the memory location pointed to by `XAR4` (`XAR4+0` to be specific).

When the 3-bit offset is 0 it's possible to leave it out:

```
The assembler also accepts ”*XARn” as an addressing mode.
This is the same encoding as the ”*+XARn[0]” mode
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im still not sure how that differs from 
MOVL *XAR4,ACC ??

Comment: @Toby: That is also covered in the same document. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now that leaves me to wonder why code would be generated that does it in *+XARn[0] manner rather than the *XARn in the first place ;)

Comment: Ah, to conclude, the reason for the bit addressing is that *XARn is a structure (members are stored contiguously) so *XAR4[0] is the first member, *XAR4[1] the second member and so on. FAB!